# p5.js problem with png alpha in webgl mode

Tags: webgl, p5.js

I noticed a problem in p5.js when rendering png images with soft alpha in WEBGL mode.
I'm rendering 10 images that are supposed to be "halos", made in photoshop all white with a blurred point mask, exported as PNG24.

In canvas mode this works ok and images overlap as supposed.
However in WEBGL mode I get a dark halo around the images
[image: here it is in WEBGL mode]

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I just discovered that it has to do to with premultiplied alpha and the way P5.js manages it. I'm gonna post an answer

Comment: it looks quite asked problem. webGL transparency is quite confusing.

What I need is a transparent canvas on whom moving pngs leave a trace.
The real problem is that if I disable rendering to alpha like 
    gl.colorMask(true, true, true, false);
it works, images blend ok, leaves trace, etc.

If I enable render to alpha, the newly drawed images's transparency "deletes" previous drawn image

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it has to do with known issues of trasparency in WebGL, and the way P5.js manages it:

https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html

In my case I managed to make it work this way:

```
//renderer is a p5.js renderer
var gl = renderer.GL; 
// Turn off rendering to alpha
gl.colorMask(true, true, true, false);
```

BUT I lost canvas transparency, that would be quite useful for this project.